# how to wrap with inkwell so every individual button in a row can work in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to wrap with inkwell so every individual button in a row can work.

Here is the code:

```
  Row( 
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, 
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
    children: [ 
      _buildSoftUIMenu(LineAwesomeIcons.bookmark,
           Colors.lightBlueAccent, 
           'Std Books'), 
     _buildSoftUIMenu(
          LineAwesomeIcons.dot_circle_o,
          Colors.deepOrangeAccent, 
          'Optional Books'), 
     _buildSoftUIMenu(LineAwesomeIcons.y_combinator,
        Colors.yellowAccent, 
        'Current Affairs'),
    ],
 ),
```

Comment: how are you creating your buttons,show code

Comment: https://github.com/mlayah/soft_ui

Comment: @griffins please refer above link and guide me! I am stucked in between! I am new to flutter and I want OnTap on each icon in a row!

Comment: please share _buildSoftUIMenu() code here, update your question

Comment: @ArpitAwasthi I shared the github code link above please check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `gesturedetector` to this widget and then call the function in your code

```
Widget _buildSoftUIMenu(icon, color, title,{Function ontap}) {
  return GestureDetector(onTap:onTap,  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: bgColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: lightColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                offset: Offset(-6, -6),
                spreadRadius: 0,
                blurRadius: 6,
              ),
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black26,
                offset: Offset(6, 6),
                spreadRadius: 0,
                blurRadius: 6,
              )
            ]),
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(
            icon,
            size: 46,
            color: color,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        title,
        style: subtitleStyle,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

then you can now build your widgets

```
_buildSoftUIMenu(LineAwesomeIcons.dot_circle_o,Colors.deepOrangeAccent, 'Optional Books',onTap:(){ print("######")},
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot bro! :) It is working! great , I would like to ask you further if I need any help!

Comment: sure do post so ,and mention me in comments ,check my profile for links

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code inside your ** _buildSoftUIMenu** function

```
Widget _buildSoftUIMenu(icon, color, title) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: onTapCallback,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        ....
        ....
        ....
      ],
    );
  );
}
```